# Qual o significado da expressão "nesse passo"?

Tags: significado, significado-em-contexto

> O dia em que eu nasci morra e pereça, / Não o queira jamais o tempo dar,
>   / Não torne mais ao mundo, e se tornar / Eclipse, nesse passo, o sol
>   padeça.

O que quer dizer a expressão "nesse passo" nesse excerto de Camões? Procurei na internet mas não encontrei o significado. Grato desde já.

Comment: Acho que pode ser "nesse ritmo", "nessa velocidade".

Comment: Eu uso tbm com a mesma ideia de ritmo...

Comment: Será? Vejam este outro exemplo: "Definição de conceptivo: O vocábulo conceptivo radica na palavra concepção. **Nesse passo**, quando alguém se refere a "equilíbrio conceptivo" significa que na proposição apresentada existe harmonia de entendimento, de concepção". Não me parece que "nesse ritmo" faça muito sentido aqui. Vou aguardar mais respostas. De todo modo, obrigado pelas opiniões.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Significa *nesse caso*. Do [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/passo):

> 12. *Fig.* Ponto, conjuntura, situação: "Mas, neste passo, assim prontos estando/ Eis o mestre, que olhando os ares anda (...)." (Luís de Camões, *Os Lusíadas*))